# Hive to pass parameters in where clause

Tags: hive, hiveql

In Hive can we pass parameter in where clause?
if yes, cloud you please explain me with one scenario?

ex:In sql
select * from mytable where col= ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
Here are several examples:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution

Here is a specific example, using a shell script, which is a very common place to use variable substitution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
    WHEREVAR=$1

    hive -e "SELECT * FROM myDB.myTable where myFirstField=${WHEREVAR};"
else

    echo "Illegal number of parameters"
```